# Convert Python dictionary to un-nested JSON object

Tags: python, json

I am seeking to use a Python dictionary with key: array pairs as a basis for constructing a database table. The dictionary is constructed as follows:

```
schema = {'names': ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'], 'type': ['STRING', 'STRING', 'INTEGER']}
```

The resulting JSON data structure that I am seeking to produce would be, for lack of better phrasing, an array of JSON elements, as below:

```
[
    {
        'names': 'Field1',
        'type': 'STRING'
    },
    {
        'names': 'Field2',
        'type': 'STRING'
    },
    {
        'names': 'Field3',
        'type': 'INTEGER'
    }
]
```

I have used the json module and attempted to do this as follows:

```
import json
schema = {'names': ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'], 'type': ['STRING', 'STRING', 'INTEGER']}
json.dumps(schema)
```

However, it gives me:

```
'{"names": ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3"], "type": ["STRING", "STRING", "INTEGER"]}'
```

I can do this by constructing the  string using `{}.format(..)` but I wanted to see if there was a more efficient manner. I have searched through numerous threads but most threads seem to do the opposite of what I am seeking to do.

Any pointers?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could zip your `names` and `types` arrays together and pass that to a list comprehension to make and array of dictionaries. Then dump to JSON:

```
import json
schema = {'names': ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'], 'type': ['STRING', 'STRING', 'INTEGER']}

# assuming values is just those two lists otherwise spell out explicitly:
l = [{"names":name, "type":field} for name, field in zip(*schema.values())] 

json.dumps(l)
```

**Result:**

```
'[{"names": "Field1", "type": "STRING"}, {"names": "Field2", "type": "STRING"}, {"names": "Field3", "type": "INTEGER"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` to get name/type pairs and build a list of small dictionaries:

```
schema = {'names': ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'], 'type': ['STRING', 'STRING', 'INTEGER']}

data = []
for n,t in zip(schema['names'], schema['type']):
    data.append({'name': n, 'type': t})
```

Answer (score 0):

By directly accessing the dictionary in a for loop, you can match each element of `names` and `type`:

```
schema = {'names': ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'], 'type': ['STRING', 'STRING', 
'INTEGER']}
output = []
names = schema["names"]
type = schema["type"]

for i in range(len(schema["names"])):
    output.append({"names": names[i], "type": type[i]})

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'names': 'Field1', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'names': 'Field2', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'names': 'Field3', 'type': 'INTEGER'}]
```